# Alert on reCAPTCHA console

Tags: laravel, recaptcha, laravel-5.5

I added the reCAPTCHA plugin on my website but I see this alert on admin console.

[image]

I'm using Laravel 5.5 for my website and I'm using the following plugin to handle reCAPTCHA module: https://github.com/thinhbuzz/laravel-google-captcha

What I need to change on my website to correct the Google alert?

Answer (score 0):

you must save your test domain here :
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

and put values inside .env

```
CAPTCHA_SECRET
CAPTCHA_SITEKEY
```

Comment: I added my website domain in the list. The plugin is working because the widget is correctly rendered in the page.